# Its possible convert this code to ruby using index and substring command using similar sintax to awk?

Tags: ruby, linux, awk

I do know if is possible generate a ruby code that use ane

like this

ruby -a -F'Name": "' -ne

this is my awk code

```
     awk -v OFS='"' -v   FS='Name": "'     '{ i2 = index($4, "\""); print  ";" substr($4, 0, i2) }'   sumacomando
```

I need to know if is possible using ruby one liner or ruby its limited for this task

only need to know if exist a similar options for index and substring in ruby Or if this options are very differents

Basically I just need to know out if ruby has awk-like functionality for this example

Please help me

Comment: Rather than posting a "convert this script for me" request, it would be better to show a sample of your input/output and explain what you're trying to do

Comment: only need to give a idea not need that convert the code

Comment: only need a method

Comment: only need to know if exist a similar options for index and substring in ruby Or  if this options are very differents

Comment: Basically I just need to know out if ruby has awk-like functionality for this example

Comment: The answer is : yes.

Comment: If you do not have these functionalities, I just want you to tell me

Comment: Your question is off-topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/128421.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Rather than add multiple comments you should think about the question prior to asking it, then write and ask the question once. It helps us when answering. Ruby is a general purpose language, `awk` is a string processing language, so Ruby is more full-featured than `awk`.

Comment: Why not go and look at the VERY well documented api for ruby and see for yourself.  In case your search engine is not working well :- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
ruby -a -F'Name": "'   -ne 'puts $F[3].split(/"/)[0]' sumacomando
```